# Performance penalty of using clone_from_slice() instead of copy_from_slice()?

Tags: performance, rust, copy, clone

In Rust, there are two methods to update the content of a slice from another slice: [`clone_from_slice()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.clone_from_slice) and [`copy_from_slice()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.copy_from_slice).  The behavior of these two functions are unsurprising - the first does a clone and expects the type to implement `Clone`, while the second does a copy and expects the type to implement `Copy`.

However, it surprises me that the documentation for `clone_from_slice` says this: "If `T` implements `Copy`, it can be more performant to use `copy_from_slice`."  It is surprising that there should be a performance difference here.  If `T` implements `Copy`, then `.clone()` is required to be equivalent to copying bits; however since the compiler knows what type `T` is, it should be able to figure out if it can do a bitwise copy even if I use `clone_from_slice`.

So where does the performance inefficiency arise from?

Comment: my suspicion is that the `copy_from_slice` case is a direct memcpy call while the `clone_from_slice` would be *relying* on the optimizer to *realize* that its equivalent to a memcpy call. while I don't know a situation that would cause it to fail (it obviously detects it in [simple cases](https://godbolt.org/z/db1bsM)), compilers/optimizers are fickle things and it may be improper for the documentation to say they'd always perform the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR**  Please check the source of [clone_from_slice](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/2fd73fabe469357a12c2c974c140f67e7cdd76d0/library/core/src/slice/mod.rs#L2930-L2938), it is visiting all the elements of slice and calling `clone` for each, while [copy_from_slice](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/2fd73fabe469357a12c2c974c140f67e7cdd76d0/library/core/src/slice/mod.rs#L3001-L3022) directly copies all the bits with `memcpy`.

**Note :** With Rust version **1.52.0**, `clone_from_slice` implemented via [specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/88f19c6dab716c6281af7602e30f413e809c5974/library/core/src/slice/mod.rs#L2972), if you'd call `clone_from_slice` with `Copy` types it will call `copy_from_slice` internally. ([reference](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.52.0/library/core/src/slice/mod.rs#L3485-L3509))

---

> If T implements `Copy`, then `.clone()` is required to be equivalent to
> copying bits

**Even if every `Copy` type would implement `Clone` by default where `clone` directly use the `copy`**; `clone_from_slice` will still traverse the slice and do the copy while traversing.

**But no this proposition is correct for primitives but not correct for the cases like below**:

```rust
#[derive(Copy)]
struct X;

impl Clone for X {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        //do some heavy operation or light(depends on the logic)

        X
    }
}
```

While `Clone` can be implemented by any logic `Copy` types will simply copy bits when duplicating an object.

> If T implements `Copy`, it can be more performant to use `copy_from_slice`

Important thing is in here, the documentation says "**it can be**" not "**it will be**", this brings possibilities like

- `Clone` implementation can directly use `Copy` implementation. For the basic types like primitives, optimizer may directly use `memcpy` instead of traversing, then we might accept this proposition as wrong because one will not be performant then other.
- `Clone` implementation can directly use `Copy` implementation. For complex types(the traversing issue above) makes this proposition correct. (I've edit the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63426583/performance-penalty-of-using-clone-from-slice-instead-of-copy-from-slice/63426992?noredirect=1#comment112156096_63426583) from @kmdreko with a bit more complex structure, [please check the result from godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/MaKa7n))
- `Clone` implementation is custom and it is a `Copy` type, this one will make this proposition correct even custom implementation is inexpensive then `copy` for the large slices using `memcpy` might be more beneficial.

Comment: Would I ever want to have a copyable type whose `Clone` doesn't just return `*self`?

Comment: @Bernard: While this is not required I cannot think of any situation where that would make sense.

Comment: @Bernard You might not be wrong but If I think from your perspective all `Copy` types should implement the `Clone` which directly copies bits, but it is not like that, this is arguable though. However I'll edit this post to explain`*self` case, it is necessary to understand this proposition.

Comment: I think you have a reasonable point that `Clone` may not directly use the `Copy` implementation.  But I'm fairly certain we would consider all such situations to be bugs.

Comment: "Even if every `Copy` type would implement `Clone` by default where clone directly use the `copy`; `clone_from_slice` still will traverse the slice and do the copy while traversing."  This claim, if true, has rather serious implications on how one should write performant libraries in Rust.  It means that when writing performant generic code, we should write a separate version types that implement `Copy` - for example, `Vec::resize`/`Vec::extend_from_slice` may not be as performant as it could have been for copyable `T` simply because it is declared as `T: Clone`. ...

Comment: ... Because the standard library implementors didn't provide versions of the `Vec` methods for `T: Copy`, I highly doubt `Clone` would generate different machine code from `Copy` for copyable types, at least when the implementation of `.clone()` just uses the `Copy` implementation.  In C++, templated functions instantiated on a trivially copyable type is expected to turn into bitwise copy even though the same template function instantiated on a nontrivial type will not, and I would expect no less from Rust.

Comment: @Bernard _we would consider all such situations to be bugs_ I am not sure about this, you can write a code into `clone` which changes the state of a program meanwhile doing a copy, this doesn't meant to be there is a bug, it might be considered as a bad design or may not, depends on the problem

Comment: @Bernard as you know `Copy` is a super trait of `Clone`, so you can use any `Copy` type to pass into function where it expects parameter like `T: Clone`. That's where the magic comes please check this [minimal example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=727072a1abb0c6bad3b46f31c95c9d13), thats how `extend_from_slice` works for std `Vec`, there is a trait called `SpecExtend`, it uses `copy_from_slice` for `Copy`  types (https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec.rs.html#2175-2189), this is a specialized implementation

Comment: @ÖmerErden I see now, it seems that my assumption that `.clone()` should be the same as a copy for `Copy` types does not hold.  This is indeed surprising - it means that to write performant generic code on arrays/slices I should write specialisations for `Copy` types.

Comment: @Bernard if you are using API like `clone/copy_from_slice`, yes you need to be aware of that, in this case API designers could  make a single function then route the performant implementation like they did in `Vec` but IMHO they did this on a purpose since arrays and slices are low level components of a language.